# not show GUI proper on RAILS_ENV=production server

Tags: html, css, ruby, rails-5.1.6

[image: on production ENV looks like this type]RAIL_ENV= testing or development server looks proper, but on production server not show proper GUI
[image: its expenses table]

Answer (score 0):

As per the images shared it seems that the css and styling is not working in production environment.

For it to work, following command would be used:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Reload the page and check if the css and js rules are being picked or not.

Comment: I was use it but not working. rake assets:precompile its work only on testing and development server not working on production server.

Comment: have you used the following command RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile?

Comment: ➜  flour_mill git:(master) RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
I, [2018-06-04T14:01:08.714582 #17476]  INFO -- : Writing /home/ak/workspace/flour_mill/public/assets/application-3844a8a2cbdd07c01c446b5baaba6eda68ca2b90898be55186860e89a02747bc.css
I, [2018-06-04T14:01:08.734131 #17476]  INFO -- : Writing /home/ak/workspace/flour_mill/public/assets/application-3844a8a2cbdd07c01c446b5baaba6eda68ca2b90898be55186860e89a02747bc.css.gz

Comment: No given error... only write new file in assets/application- 3844a8a2cbdd07c01c446b5baaba6eda68ca2b90898be55186860e89a02747bc.css

Comment: is this line enabled in environments/production.rb 
config.serve_static_files = true

Comment: can you not precompile in your development environment, then push the changes to your repo and then restart your rails server (after pulling the latest version of your code)?

Comment: my line = config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?   your line = config.serve_static_files = true

Comment: config.serve_static_files = true
after this line show tables properly but some images or icon are not show.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using heroku perhaps you could try it on heroku. First run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` then run `git add .` within your working folder. Commit, push and then push to heroku master. See if you still have this issue.